# How can I Update my Theme

Tags: themes, updates

I Just want to know how can I update my Wordpress theme manually on live site. Actually I am using plugin called "WP Total Cache" My entire website styles is messed up when I try to update wordpress theme via ftp.

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you've modified the theme's built-in stylesheet, then any changes would be overwritten when you update the theme.

If that's the case, you have a choice: either don't update the theme, or move your modifications to any type of CUSTOM CSS area that the theme may provide.

Comment: Thanks Jennifer for response, Can you tell me please there is no other way to update old version theme with new version ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating the theme design but are not able to see the live changes and as you wrote, messed up design, you should purge the WP Total Cache.

For that go to WP Total Cache and click on 'Delete Cache' or any similar option.

Also, be sure to check the validity of your browser cache. You can check that in your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think you mean "W3 Total Cache".
GoTo admin panel hover on performance -> click on empty all caches.
I think this may help you.
And make sure all files have same name.

Comment: Thanks Sanjeet I already tried this but there is some issues in my minify cache. and still facing same issues.